# Is there a jQuery lightbox plugin that has thumbnails inside the box?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a lightbox style plugin in jQuery that displays thumbnails at the bottom of the picture (or video, or whatever).

I found plenty of lightbox plugins, but none that allows navigation by thumbnail inside the box. The plugin must be able to open images, swf and inline content. I realize that jQuery will not be able to generate the thumbnails and that's ok.

Do you have any good ones to suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/). Perfect for your needs. Source code [here](http://github.com/aino/galleria).

Comment: Galleria seems to be working only with images... Did I miss something on the Web site about swf and other contents?

Answer (score 0):

The only ones I could find were http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery/index.htm and http://koti.mbnet.fi/mallery/

Answer (score 0):

maybe http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/